# Wikidata Query Service not showing data on wikipedia page

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, wikidata-query-service

I am new to the Wikidata Query Service.

I want to find all the `installed capacity` of `power stations`.

I tried the following: [Wikidata Query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fpumped_storage_hydroelectricity%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fpumped_storage_hydroelectricity%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ200974.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%201000)

```
SELECT ?power_station ?power_stationLabel ?installed_capacity WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }

  ?power_station wdt:P31 wd:Q159719.
  OPTIONAL { ?power_station wdt:P2109 ?installed_capacity. }
}
LIMIT 100
```

What I don't understand is why when I go on the Wikipedia page of a power station, more often than not, I can find a Nameplate Capacity. (ef: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pembroke_Power_Station)

Yet, I don't get that result from the Wikidata query. That is, I get the power plant name, but not the power capacity.

I also tried the other way around, looking for all the instances of Nameplate Capacity, but that only returns the `installed capacity` (wd:P2109).

Comment: Pembroke Power Station isn't instance of nameplate capacity, but of power station. See [query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ159719.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%201000)

Comment: I don't get the question. Look at the Wikidata entry for [Pembroke Power Station](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2944691) There is no such value, thus, what do you want to query for? Wikipedia is **not** Wikidata. Not all information is in Wikidata. Nor is it in DBpedia.

Comment: @AKSW Thanks, I think I was confused as I thought that Wikidata was the database used by Wikipedia. Does such database exists ?

Comment: No, it's the other way around. Wikidata and DBpedia extract information from Wikipedia. Wikipedia is not a database. There are Wikipedia dumps, but those are just the set of Wikipedia documents. Note, Wikipedia is more or less unstructured data - although the infoboxes seem to be kind of semi-structured.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the question becomes irrelevant then. Would it be good practice for me to delete it ?

Comment: I don't think you have to. You could simply provide the answer and accept it. Others might have the same resp. a similar question, thus, it's always good to have an answer then.

Comment: Simply Wikidata is a giant database, and Wikipedia is a giant encyclopedia. The first contain items, the second contain texts.